# Баг с blur(), помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: css, blur

Доброго времени суток!

С последним обновлением Google Chrome до 66 версии, появился очевидный баг с анимацией при наличии там filter:blur(). При наведении картинка мигает.

В Opere тоже наблюдается такой эффект, но намного слабее, некое дергание. Такой же эффект был и в предыдущей версии Google Chrome, а с последней версией все стало еще хуже. В Firefox же все гладко как и задумывалось. Это как-нибудь возможно исправить?

Наглядный пример на Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdpvdW

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="target" class="blur">This element has a background-image, which should be blured</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-layer">
    <input id="searchMain" class="animated fadeIn delay">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
target{
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/100);
}
.blur {
  -webkit-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -ms-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.delay {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blur {
  to {
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
@keyframes blur {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Последняя версия Chrome - 76

Comment: В вашем примере мигания не наблюдаю. Единственно, периодически после наведения, когда blur убирается совсем, в этот момент заметно маленькое подергивание всего изображения. Вы именно про это?

Comment: Eleferen, да, именно про него. Не знаете, как это убрать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В моем хроме помогло не нулевое значение для blur, например:

```
filter: blur(0.01px);
```

```css
#target{
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/100);
}
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .2s linear,-webkit-filter .4s linear;
}

.blur:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.01px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0.01px);
    -o-filter: blur(0.01px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0.01px);
    filter: blur(0.01px);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="target" class="blur">This element has a background-image, which should be blured</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё работает! И как я не этого не додумался...

Comment: @ХорошийЧеловек ну это все же больше хак, не должно такого быть конечно же

Comment: Вот тут обсуждение кажется этой проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome и решение так и не найдено судя по всему.

Comment: @Eleferen там про 3д трансформы речь, однако проблема наверняка та же, резкий переход на 0 в какой-то момент

Comment: @Stranger in the Q добавил до 200 :)  за хороший ответ